# SSRS 2008 Display Toggling causing bug with Show or Hide Based on an Expression

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I am building a report in SSRS 2008 Report Builder, and I'm setting the visibility property on my details row group. I want the visibility of this row to be based on a parameter called Show All Details that is either true or false, and chosen by the user at runtime. I also want each detail row's display to be toggled by it's summary row column.

Each piece of this functionality works fine - the whole report can be expanded or collapsed based on the Show All Details parameters, and each detail row can be expanded or collapsed by clicking on its Summary column.

But when I have 1 or a few rows expanded individually, and then I change the Show All Details parameter to yes, those expanded rows actually collapse instead of staying expanded. The same happens when I do the reverse and have a few indivual rows collapsed, then change the Show all details parameter to no; the collapsed rows actually expand instead of staying collapsed. Is this a bug in SSRS 2008?

Comment: You probably set ToggleItem, right? If yes, toggle would hide if the current state is visible.

Comment: I did set ToggleItem, correct. The toggling is working fine, but when I have a few items toggled and then change the Show All Details parameter, it doesn't set the visibility to Yes or No for all of them, it seems to only be switching it to the opposite of what it was set as. So, if an item is toggled/expanded, and I hit Show All Detail, it's setting the visibility from Yes to No, instead of just keeping it as Yes.

Comment: No, it is the correct behavior. As I said it `toggles` the state. If the item was expanded and hit the toggle button/check again it __will__ retract.

Comment: ToggleItem can only be refer to textboxes so I don't understand how this is connected to the Show All Details Parameter?

Comment: Parameters are really only meant to be used once to generate the report, not to interactively change what's already there. It would be better to add a textbox with code to control the changes and format it to look like a button.

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem. You set visibility property directly to row.
You need set visibility to goup in "Row Group" window. What include all other rows in group and sub groups.